# Left outer join on two columns only joining on one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want this code to not just join on clientlocation, but also on clientdivision so it only matches if clientlocation is A and clientdivision is B. What am I doing wrong?

```
  left outer join EMEA_TRANS.dbo.CT_AutomationEmail_TEST B
      on  (B.[CLIENTLOCATION] = A.[CT Client Location]
      and  B.[ClientDivision] = A.[CLIENTDIVISION])
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the wanted result. (As formatted text, not images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: left outer join is the same of left join, try to take out the ''outer''

Answer (score 1):

If match is not found then `LEFT JOIN` still returns one row where columns from left table contain values and columns from right table are all NULL.

An `INNER JOIN` will not produce that row.

Answer (score 0):

It must be data related. I don't think either of the conditions are considered to display the output. And yet, providing a sample data would make it easier.